# Raspberry Pi in Car Stereo (touchscreen)

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I hope this is the correct place to post this, if not, let me know!

So I have been researching how to connect a raspberry pi to a car stereo. I have a few Pi's lying around and I ordered a stereo that will be here soon: http://www.ebay.com/itm/400766533972?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Now I have been trying to figure out some things. I know that I can use the stereo as output over the RCA cables in the back. However, I am thinking of using HDMI to RCA converter, but would A/V to RCA be better quality video? Secondly is there any way to get the touch screen to work on the raspberry pi? I am trying to rap my head around it and my initial thought is that it can't be done because RCA is just displaying the information on the raspberry pi, not sending anything back. Is this assumption correct? If not, how do I set the pi up to be able to detect touches on the screen.

Somewhat unrelated, if the touchscreen won't work, what is the next best way to receive input from the driver? Voice control isn't very complex on the pi, but it requires an active internet connection which could be achieved by tethering it to an iPhone but that's annoying and would use a ton of data. Next best would be a keyboard... but that would be absolutely stupid because I also need to be able to drive. I was thinking about maybe a MYOs, the little devices that detect muscle movements? Any other thoughts?

Thank you for any help or thoughts you have!

Comment: Stack Overflow is specifically for questions about computer programming, so this post is off-topic here.  You might try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead though.

Comment: I believe there's a special PI site which I will try and migrate this to. But keep in mind HDMI is digital and RCA is analog so there is no standalone conversion plug to convert the two. You won't notice any difference in quality between HDMI and RCA unless whatever is driving the RCA has a bad digital to analog converter (i.e. the pi). Here's a sample touchscreen, including some info on what you plug it into: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/. In short it's probably easiest to connect RCA directly your stereo and work out the display seperately